# Unit Test gives different result from custom (by hand) test with same parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, soap

I have a C# web service application (SOAP) and I want to create create some unit tests. So I created a simple function to check if a record exists in my database (SQL Server). When I tested it with SoapUI I got the correct result the record exists, but when I ran my test it failed it didn't find my result.

I added the web service DLL as a reference and this is my code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void FindItemTest()
{
    MyWebService ws = new MyWebService ();
    Proxy.FindItemRequest request = new Proxy.FindItemRequest ();
    request.itemId = 55550;

    Proxy.FindItemResponse response = ws.FindItem(mc, request);

    Assert.AreEqual(0, response.result);
}
```

This returns -1, the item has not been found, but when I ran the same ID in SOAP UI I get 0, item found. So I was hoping anyone knows why am I getting this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a try/catch block that returns -1 if an error is thrown? It's possible your connection to the database is failing and throwing an error.

Comment: I just posted the answer, but yes I do if the connection failed it should return -1000, but I got -1 as not found, I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests should never go past a certain scope (the unit, generally a class). In other words, you shouldn't touch the DB - that's already system (integration testing).

Your unit test should rather just test the logic inside that web service method, whilst mocking the layer handling the DB calls.

Otherwise, if you want to go down the system test path, you would have to issue a request towards the url (port number & all) your service resides, not through a direct reference to it.

Only wrote this as an answer because it's too long for a comment, you'll need to provide more details if you need specific answers.

Comment: So what you're saying is I can't have SqlCommands  inside the methods I'm testing ? Regarding more details, there is not much more to it, the function is basically a SqlCommand with a connection that select the item with the given ID if not found returns -1, else 0.

Comment: Say you want to test a controller: instead of calling SqlCommands directly, you can abstract that functionality into an interface (IServiceRepository), create another implementation for it (MockServiceRepository)- this can be as simple as just returning some dummy data; you'll then need to wire all this up so that through a certain mechanism your consumer can swap between the 2 different service implementations (this somewhat implies that you're using Dependency Injection).
Testing the actual DAL is certainly a lot trickier (even without using an ORM), and might not be worth looking into.

Comment: Well that actually doesn't work for my the whole point of writing this test was to test the methods with the data in the database, but I did a workaround, I set my webservice as a Service Reference and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best solution but it worked for me, I just set my web service app as a Service Reference, like it would normally be used in a client program, and called the method from there. This worked, but if anyone has a better solution please post an answer.